# Jinja and Ansible - Extract "version" from "versions" where environment_ids list is empty

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I'm trying to get the version text from one of these items where the versions environment_ids list is empty. This is for foreman content-view version deletion. Below is a sample dataset and for the life of me I can't get it.

Since the sample data is mostly code, stackoverflow is asking for more details.

Beyond this, in the playbook I'll be using the ansible community collection theforeman.foreman.content_view_version do delete the older unused versions.

Sample Data:

```
item:
- auto_publish: false
  component_ids:
  - 10
  - 11
  environments:
  - activation_keys:
    - 1
    hosts: []
    id: 1
    label: Library
    name: Library
    permissions:
      readable: true
  - activation_keys: []
    hosts: []
    id: 2
    label: DEV
    name: DEV
    permissions:
      readable: true
  - activation_keys: []
    hosts: []
    id: 3
    label: PROD
    name: PROD
    permissions:
      readable: true
  generated_for: none
  hosts: []
  id: 4
  import_only: false
  label: system-tester
  last_published: 2023-07-17 14:15:24 UTC
  name: comp Repo (noarch)
  version_count: 2
  versions:
  - environment_ids:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
    id: 9
    published: 2023-07-17 14:03:01 UTC
    version: '2.0'
  - environment_ids:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
    id: 12
    published: 2023-07-17 14:15:24 UTC
    version: '2.1'
- auto_publish: false
  component_ids:
  - 10
  - 11
  environments:
  - activation_keys:
    - 1
    hosts: []
    id: 1
    label: Library
    name: Library
    permissions:
      readable: true
  - activation_keys: []
    hosts: []
    id: 2
    label: DEV
    name: DEV
    permissions:
      readable: true
  - activation_keys: []
    hosts: []
    id: 3
    label: PROD
    name: PROD
    permissions:
      readable: true
  generated_for: none
  hosts: []
  id: 4
  import_only: false
  label: system-tester2
  last_published: 2023-07-17 14:15:24 UTC
  name: comp Repo (noarch)
  version_count: 2
  versions:
  - environment_ids: []
    id: 9
    published: 2023-07-17 14:03:01 UTC
    version: '2.0'
  - environment_ids:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
    id: 12
    published: 2023-07-17 14:15:24 UTC
    version: '2.1'
- activation_keys:
  - id: 3
    name: lx
  auto_publish: false
  component_ids:
  - 10
  - 11
  environments:
  - activation_keys:
    - 1
    hosts: []
    id: 1
    label: Library
    name: Library
    permissions:
      readable: true
  - activation_keys: []
    hosts: []
    id: 2
    label: DEV
    name: DEV
    permissions:
      readable: true
  - activation_keys: []
    hosts: []
    id: 3
    label: PROD
    name: PROD
    permissions:
      readable: true
  generated_for: none
  hosts: []
  id: 4
  import_only: false
  label: system-tester3
  last_published: 2023-07-17 14:15:24 UTC
  name: comp Repo (noarch)
  version_count: 2
  versions:
  - environment_ids: []
    id: 9
    published: 2023-07-17 14:03:01 UTC
    version: '2.0'
  - environment_ids:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
    id: 12
    published: 2023-07-17 14:15:24 UTC
    version: '2.1'
```

`{{ (item.resources| map(attribute='version') | list ) }}`

Comment: Your example data doesn't have a key named `resources`, so I wouldn't expect `item.resources` to yield anything other than an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two items in your sample data for which `environment_ids` is an empty list. We can use a [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org) expression to extract the version text, like this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item|json_query('[].versions[?!environment_ids].version[]') }}"
```

Given your sample data, the above `debug` tasks produces the output:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "2.0",
        "2.0"
    ]
}
```